# Get Next Iteration Value in Current Iteration each function Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have written a snippet which goes through all the input tags and checks their values. I have some conditions that I will apply later (haven't been done in this snippet). What I want to have is the next iteration value in the current iteration. Like php for loop can we do some counter+1 to get the next index value? What my snippet is doing is that it iterates through the table and searches for input tag in each column. I want to get the input tag of the next column in the same row.

```
        $("table#table- tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).index() + 1;
            var td = $(this).find('td');
            $(td).each(function () {
                var input = $(this).find('input');

                $(input).each(function () {
                    if (!$(input).val()) {
                        $('input._name').val("");
                    } else {
                        //gives the current input tag value here!
                    }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: are you trying to get the next row? along with the current. or the `value` of the next `input` along with the current one

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am trying to get the next column of the same row.

Comment: just posted an answer for you please verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the next `input` by using `eq` and `index` functions inside the `.each` if i understood correctly, see below demo I have reduced the script to address the actual problem

```js
$("table#table- tr").each(function() {
  var row = $(this);
  var td = $(this).find('td');

  $(td).each(function() {
    var input = $(this).find('input');

    /*this get the next input and print value in console*/
    var nextInput = row.find('td:eq(' + parseInt($(this).index() + 1) + ') input');
    if (nextInput.length) {
      console.log('current input value = ' + input.val(), 'next td input value = ' + nextInput.val());
    }
    /*this get the next input and print value in console*/

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-">
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' value="1"></td>
    <td><input type='text' value="2"></td>
    <td><input type='text' value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' value="1"></td>
    <td><input type='text' value="2"></td>
    <td><input type='text' value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' value="1"></td>
    <td><input type='text' value="2"></td>
    <td><input type='text' value="3"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope is this what you looking for 'cause isn't clear 100%

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
  <title>yeah</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" action="">
 <table width="900">
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="c1" id="c1" value="1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="c2" id="c2" value="2"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="c3" id="c3" value="3"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="c4" id="c4" value="4"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="c5" id="c5" value="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="c6" id="c6" value="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="c7" id="c7" value="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="c8" id="c8" value="8"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="c9" id="c9" value="9"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ca" id="ca" value="10"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cb" id="cb" value="11"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cc" id="cc" value="12"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 
 <textarea name="tx1" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
 
var index=1;
 $('input').each(function(index) {
  $(this).before(index);
  $('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+'\n'+$(this).val());
  index++;
 });

});
//-->
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

the answer ? ok !
How is work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
this is a kind of onload so you'll have access to all elements when everything is loaded
});
```

A code like this
    `$('textarea').val('row1\nrow2')` add 2 rows in textarea
 `$('textarea').val()` should get the curent value of textarea
so `$('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+'\n'+'SOMETHING');` should add a new row with the old value of textarea plus a new row with the text SOMETHING
jquery get ALL input elements FROM THE PAGE with this

```
 $('input').each(function(index) {    
    console.log($(this).val());
 });
```

`$(this).before("100");` is adding in the front of current html element '100'

inside that each here is our value inside the current input in loop = `$(this).val()`

var index=1;  is meaning global ,use it everywhere! 
inside the loop 'each' `index++;`  after this increase index by 1 to be useful before the next input element

..easy job

Comment: well  i will explain adding something there visible

Comment: This is also working. But Muhammad's answer was more close to what I required. Am giving +1 :)